# Why s:action did not be executed every time?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

In a JSP page, I used an s:action to call an action.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>online shop market</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>welcome</h1>
    <s:action name="listallAction" executeResult="true" />   
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="loginAction" class="action.CustomerAction" method="login">
        <result name="SUCCESSLOGIN">/welcome.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="listallAction" class="action.ItemAction" method="listall">
        <result name="SUCCESSLISTALL">/allitems.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

For easy to understand, I saved some code here.
My problem is: In the first situation, when it is doing the loginAction, after successfully log in, it will map to this page and call the listallAction. The listallAction is implemented successfully, and the content is included in this page. I see the URL is http://localhost:8080/XXProject/loginAction. In the second situation, after launching the tomcat, in the browser, I just called the welcome.jsp page, the url is http://localhost:8080/XXProject/welcome.jsp. This time, it did not execute s:action! The server told me: There is no Action mapped for action name listallAction. - [unknown location]. Is this problem related to the url path? I googled some information about the url path and got more confused about it.

Comment: Why do you use `<s:action>` at all? Redirect from the welcome page to some action and show results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answered myself, kind of feel cold.....I added the namespace="/" in the s:action tag. It success! Just wondering why s:action did not add the namespace in the package in the XML file.